# How to Step into NServiceBus 2.0 with Debugger and also Navigate in it with Resharper?

Tags: nservicebus

We've just newly decided to use NServiceBus on our project and we're experiencing some problems. Rather than "ask for a fish" every time we hit an issue, we'd prefer to "teach ourselves to fish". This means setting things up so we can step into the NServiceBus source code and understand NServiceBus more deeply.

We need some help figuring out how to pull this off. It is unclear how to get Visual Studio to successfully build NServiceBus upon each compile, since NServiceBus comes with its own Nant build process that uses ILMerge to create consolidated assemblies and so forth.

We have already tried building NServiceBus with the Nant script and then referencing those dlls and pdb's. However, that does not let us step everywhere, and it also does not let VS.NET and Resharper navigate via "Find Usages" and other features.

So what we would really like to create is a VS.NET Solution that builds our in-house software and NServiceBus, and allows us to seamlessly Step and Navigate between them.

Is this possible? What would we need to do to pull this off?

Comment: Hi great question.. I wrote a blog post on debugging into nservice bus using the pdb files.. but would be really interested to hear if you manage to get an answer to this question. http://www.craftyfella.com/2010/12/debugging-into-nservicebus-so-you-can.html

Comment: Yours would be the most thorough answer I've seen. I really think the right thing to do for future readers would be for you to make this an answer. I'm sure you don't want to blow your own horn too much, but people would be well served coming here and finding your blog. If you make this a response, I'll vote it up and accept it, which makes the "StackOverflow Wiki" capture and highlight the correct info. (and btw, I never really got any great info about this. I wound up awkwardly hitting a few breakpoints and finding my way through, but it was not a smooth process at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite the exact answer you were looking for, but you can check out the post i made on debugging into NServiceBus which involves the following steps:

1. Downloading the source code.
2. Building the source code using the
   "build.bat"
3. Then referencing the
   dlls and pdb files in your
   solutions, so that you can step into
   the NServiceBus source code.

I've successfully change the logging behaviour to always to a Message.ToString() in our code so that the Log4Net logs were a bit clearer.

Check it out here:

http://www.craftyfella.com/2010/12/debugging-into-nservicebus-so-you-can.html

Hope it helps.

Dave

Comment: thanks. I ended up doing something along those lines, but less thorough. I think your info is the best info out there on debugging NServiceBus.